# Boot very slow . Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, apt, 16.04

the boot takes around 1min 6.382s !
output when I enter systemd-analyze in terminal:

```
Startup finished in 5.024s (kernel) + 1min 1.358s (userspace) = 1min 6.382s
```

system-analyze blame

```
     44.051s apt-daily.service
     14.293s networking.service
     12.632s grub-common.service
     12.135s irqbalance.service
     11.782s ondemand.service
     11.754s apport.service
     11.653s speech-dispatcher.service
      9.340s dev-sda1.device
      9.245s apparmor.service
      8.661s ModemManager.service
      8.269s lightdm.service
      7.116s snapd.firstboot.service
      6.566s NetworkManager.service
      4.899s accounts-daemon.service
      3.729s console-setup.service
      3.482s thermald.service
      3.431s gpu-manager.service
      2.036s rsyslog.service
      1.664s polkitd.service
      1.570s avahi-daemon.service
      1.558s keyboard-setup.service
      1.495s systemd-journald.service
      1.464s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
```

Anything to do with apt-daily.service ?

Thanks !